# Liquibase Failed SQL: (933) error while inserting data in Oracle

Tags: liquibase, oracle19c

I am new to Liquibase and I am currently trying to migrate our existing Sql scripts to **Liquibase sql changesheet**.

While trying to execute the following insert statement via Liquibase:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset authentic:DATA-CORE-NEW-1 splitStatements:false
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6) VALUES (789,67,1,'Backslash','\',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
--rollback DELETE FROM TABLE_A
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set 
install/DATA/CORE/new_DATA.sql::DATA-CORE-NEW-1::axx2323:
    Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    [Failed SQL: (933) INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6) VALUES (789,67,1,'Backslash','\',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);]
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

I am suspecting that the issue is with the '\' (backslash) character.
I tried changing the '\' to '\\' but it didn't worked and I am getting the same error.

My Liquibase version is : version 4.2.2 #36

**Note:** I don't want to change the format of the changesheet as I have too many of them and changing the format will take too much time.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: try to remove `;` from the end of the sql script

Comment: Does that insert command work if you run it manually in a database terminal? You could also try putting a newline between the statement and the rollback command.

Answer (score 1):

You should either remove

`;` after SQL command or

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset authentic:DATA-CORE-NEW-1 splitStatements:false
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6) VALUES (789,67,1,'Backslash','\',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
--rollback DELETE FROM TABLE_A
```

`splitStatements:false`

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset authentic:DATA-CORE-NEW-1
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6) VALUES (789,67,1,'Backslash','\',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
--rollback DELETE FROM TABLE_A
```